# Alpine Linux: apk cache APKINDEX checksum details

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

In Alpine Linux, when I run the command `apk update` it looks at my `/etc/apk/repositories` file and downloads the `APKINDEX.tar.gz` file from each repository. It then renames each `APKINDEX` `tar` file using a checksum to be in the format `APKINDEX.12345678.tar.gz` where `12345678` represent some checksum.

I've been trying to understand how this checksum works because I'd like to update the package listing for an offline Alpine installation. To better understand it, I am reading the [source code for the apk tool](https://github.com/alpinelinux/apk-tools/tree/master/src). From the source, I understand that the checksum is 4 bytes of a SHA1 hash, but I can't figure out what the SHA1 hash is taken on.

Where are the 4 bytes of the `APKINDEX` checksum coming from? Specifically, what is the algorithm for recalculating it? I apologize if this has already been answered but I've spent multiple days searching the internet and not come up with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It is a straightforward 4 bytes of the SHA1 hash of the repository name. So, like, if the repository is `https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main`, the SHA1 hash of that URL is `49104001a9bfdb6b41229ce23bb30b7aec6c4fdd` and the `APKINDEX` file will be `APKINDEX.49104001.tar.gz`